# Running multiple functions concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, oop, multiprocessing

The goal of my code is to run both `westernEurope.infection()` and `easternEurope.infection()` at the same time. The thing is, I also want to be able to output the sum of the `self.cases` from both of the objects. I have never used multiprocessing or threading before, so was wondering which one is better to use in this case, as well as guidance on how the code should be presented

```
class Region:
    def __init__(self, name, population, cases, deaths):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population
        self.cases = cases
        self.deaths = deaths

    def infection(self):
        while self.population > self.cases:
            self.cases = self.cases + random.randint(0,8)
            
westernEurope = Region("Western Europe", 1000, 0, 0)
westernEurope.infection()

easternEurope = Region("Eastern Europe", 1000, 0, 0)
easternEurope.infection()

#totalCases = will print the sum of self.cases of both easternEurope and westernEurope
```

Comment: Have you checked `ThreadPoolExecutor` ? Since your code has no I/O bound operation, multiprocessing is a way to go given that you have more than 1 core CPU.

Comment: For compute-bound tasks such as these, it's best to use `multiprocessing`. This is because, due to the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), Python doesn't really run threads concurrently except when they do I/O.